# Setting a self signed certificate into list of windows certificates does not resolve SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT

Tags: windows-10, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate

I set `http.sslbackend=schannel` and imported my self-signed certificate into windows 10 (Personal | Certificates) pane in MMC. Now, I'm trying to clone a repository hosted on a server configured with the self-signed certificate.

As far as I understood as long as having the certificate in windows (explained above) git should not complain about the certificate. This is not the case. whenever I try to clone I'm getting:

```sh
unable to access https://server.com/project.git : schannel: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0X80090325) - THE CERTIFICATE CHAIN WAS ISSUED BY AN AUTHORITY THAT IS NOT TRUSTED.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Add the certificate to the **Trusted root certification authority**

Comment: Git relies on libcurl, which in turn relies on your OS's standard setup. I updated your tags.

Comment: @Max, I added my certificate to **Trusted root certification authority** closed `cmd` open it again (at this point I was expecting it to work) but it did not work until I restarted my Windows!